# How to remove a substring enclosed inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom, replace

I have below string

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html></html>"
```

in which I want to remove the below part using JavaScript

```
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
```

such that the result should be

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html></html>
```

I have tries something like

```
console.log('Data', data);
data.replace("PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" /"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd/", "");
console.log('Data', data);
```

where data contains the complete string

but unfortunately both the logs print the same value.

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the qsn

Comment: Don't use `"` as your string syntax. Use `\`` or `'` instead. As your string value has double quotes in it

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1:

```js
const str = `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html></html>`;
const index1 = str.indexOf('HTML');
const index2 = str.indexOf('<html>');
const result = `${str.slice(0, index1 + 4)}${str.slice(index2 - 1)}`;
console.log(result);
```

Variant 2:

```js
const str = `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html></html>`;
const index = str.indexOf('><html>');
const result = `${str.slice(0, 14)}${str.slice(index)}`;
console.log(result);
```

Variant 3 (without $):

```js
const str = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html></html>';
const index = str.indexOf('><html>');
const firstPart = str.slice(0, 14);
const secondPart = str.slice(index);
const result = firstPart + secondPart;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I need it in ES5 becoz '$' is available only from ES6

Comment: Also I can't assure if the make the input string to start with ` since its coming from a response

Answer (score 1):

Adding the HTML as string and replacing the part that you want to remove.

```js
let str = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"><html></html>";
str = str.replace(" PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"", "");

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have initial or final quotes:

```js
let str = `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html></html>`;
str = str.replace(`PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"`, '');
console.log(str);
```

But I suspect you are looking for something more, so please elaborate.

Comment: what does the last line do?

Comment: it throws "invalid character" error for the second line

Comment: It removes the initial and final `"` characters that are present in the provided string (unless is a typo). On my side it runs correctly under Node.js 12, Node.js 14, Chrome. Where are you running it?

Comment: @Amaarrockz does your string starts with "<!DOCTYPE or <!DOCTYPE  ? As I'm not understanging if your code contains the `"` characters ?

Comment: Its a string only but on printing it on console it shows <!DOCTYPE and not "<!DOCTYPE

Comment: Its a string only but on console it prints as <DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code to ignore quotation marks and the text between them. If starting quote is identified, `flag` is set `true`. While `flag == true` we ignore the characters. Finally when ending quote is identified, `flag` is set false.

```js
const str = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"><html></html>"
var flag = false
var newStr = ""
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  if(str[i] == '"') flag = !flag
  if(!flag && str[i]!='"') newStr += str[i]
}
console.log(newStr)
```

Hopefully it fulfils your requirement. If you want to handle nested quotes, then let me know that.

Comment: this might remove the class names as well if they are enclosed in double quotes

Comment: You can add check for `class` `id` etc. to include the quotes that belong to them.